# Problem with signing GDB on Big Sur

Tags: security, keychain, code-signing

I am trying to make GNU debugger `gdb` work on macOS 11.6 Big Sur.
You need to sign the binary to make it work.
I use instructions from here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin

However, when I try to sign the binary `gdb` with the generated certificate, I get an error that the certificate is not in the keychain, although it is, indeed, in the `System` keychain:

```
$ security find-certificate -c gdb-cert
keychain: "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
version: 256
class: 0x80001000
attributes:
    "alis"<blob>="gdb-cert"
    "cenc"<uint32>=0x00000003
    "ctyp"<uint32>=0x00000001
    "hpky"<blob>=0xE0EF37F066B9B1387C9BD114986A11E180835908  "\340\3577\360f\271\2618|\233\321\024\230j\021\341\200\203Y\010"
    "issu"<blob>=0x30203111300F06035504030C086764622D63657274310B3009060355040613024445  "0 1\0210\017\006\003U\004\003\014\010gdb-cert1\0130\011\006\003U\004\006\023\002DE"
    "labl"<blob>="gdb-cert"
    "skid"<blob>=<NULL>
    "snbr"<blob>=0x01
    "subj"<blob>=0x30203111300F06035504030C086764622D63657274310B3009060355040613024445  "0 1\0210\017\006\003U\004\003\014\010gdb-cert1\0130\011\006\003U\004\006\023\002DE"

$ codesign --entitlements gdb-entitlement.xml -fs gdb-cert $(which gdb)
error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?